# I am trying make the raspberry pi camera work with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I tried making this code work with the raspberry pi cam.
how do you make the cv2.VideoCapture(0)  recognise the raspberry pi camera as the designated camera

```
import cv2

def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
   d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)
   d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
   return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  

winName = "Movement Indicator"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

t_minus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

while True:
   cv2.imshow( winName, diffImg(t_minus, t, t_plus) )

# Read next image
t_minus = t
t = t_plus
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

key = cv2.waitKey(10)
if key == 27:
   cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
   break

 print ("Goodbye")
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `cv2.VideoCapture()` for RaspiCam.

The `cv2.VideoCapture()` is only for USB camera, not for CSI camera.

If you want to use RaspiCam for capturing, you can refer this
[tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box?view=all#hardware)

**Update:** The answer is no longer correct since now you can use `cv2.VideoCapture()` as the comment mentioned bellow.

Comment: Thanks. But on my laptop, `cv2.VideoCapture()` works with integrated webcam. Why it should fail with integrated webcam of Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: Yes, because your integrated webcam could be consider as a usb camera. The Raspi Camera is another type of hardware (serial interface), and the official OpenCV is not support to detect this type of camera.

Comment: As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37530016/1135819) shows, it is actually possible after loading a kernel module.

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture also works for IP cameras.  The the raspberry pi camera is the odd duck here.

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture() can be used with the Raspberry Pi camera (not using RaspiCam software) but instead by running `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` which makes the Raspberry Pi camera visible (which you can see with `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` ).

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I developed on a rasperry pi with raspicam, an interface for opencv. 
I thought that the video capture in pure cv only works for usb devices

You can download raspicam under 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you need to find the location # of the raspberry pi camera and change

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

to

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(Camera#)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(
            get_jetson_gstreamer_source(), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER
        )
```