# Video don't shows up on Raspbian

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried do an example for test my Camera Raspberry and the video window don't shows up. I've done an example from opencv site. I compile the code and nothing happens. The video window don't shows up. The code How can I see the video?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(cap.isOpened()):  # check !
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post pics of code. [Paste the actual text into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45641718/edit). Vist the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you tried changing the camera input to `1` instead? Does the camera even _light up_?

Comment: What does `cap.isOpened()` return?

Comment: I believe @JohnnyMopp meant you should include your code as part of your question and not remove it entirely ;)

Comment: the camera works fine. I've take an photo by terminal using the command raspistill.

Comment: Ok! I will repost it

Comment: Can you try replacing your `while(cap.isOpened())` to `while True` instead?

Comment: If all fails, consider looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583533/videocapture-open0-wont-recognize-pi-cam) question