# OpenCV returning none type object instead of byte like object on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pygame

I'm working on a openCV+pygame project on raspberry pi. I tested the project on Mac and it worked fine. However, when it comes to Raspberry Pi, it shows "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'".

I figured out this error is from:

```
buffer = get_image()
# error is from next line
buffer = Image.frombytes('RGB', (cam_h_rez, cam_v_rez),  buffer_1)
pixels = buffer.load()
```

where get_image() function is the following:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#capture image
def get_image():
    retval, im = camera.read()
    return im
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure if I can help you, but you should always provide the complete traceback here and also post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It turns out raspberry pi does not automatically give openCV camera permission. Use:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

solved the problem.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530016/4491353

Comment: Note: it is an "L" not a "1" for bcm2835-v4l2.